# I need to make a countdown of where the images show up and move in random directions. I could only use Javascript

Tags: javascript

So I have to make a countdown of where the images show up and they slide in random directions. I have gotten the countdown to work, but the shapes do not move. I could only use Javascript, no JQuery. Here is my code so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/IyamSIM/L6umLkt8/

```js
function countdown() {
  var seconds;
  var way;
  seconds = document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML;
  seconds = parseInt(seconds, 10);

  if (seconds == 1) {
    way = document.getElementById('countdown');
    way.innerHTML = "End";

    ham();
    sis();
    wash();

    return;
  }

  seconds--;
  way = document.getElementById('countdown');
  way.innerHTML = seconds;
  timeoutMyStop = setTimeout(countdown, 100);

}

countdown();

function ham() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("ham");
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 8);

  function frame() {
    if (pos == 550) {} else {
      pos++;
      elem.style.bottom = pos + 'px';
      elem.style.left = pos + 'px';

    }
  }
}

function sis() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("sis");
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 8);

  function frame() {
    if (pos == 250) {} else {
      pos++;
      elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
    }
  }
}

function wash() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("wash");
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 8);

  function frame() {
    if (pos == 290) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++;
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
      elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
img{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<h1>Countdown Surprise Assignment</h1>
<center><div id="countdown">10</div></center>

<img id ="ham" src="https://simranjits-swamped-story.neocities.org/FINAL_PROJECT/hamilton.jpg">

<img id ="sis" src="https://simranjits-swamped-story.neocities.org/FINAL_PROJECT/sisters.jpg">

<img id ="sis" src="https://simranjits-swamped-story.neocities.org/FINAL_PROJECT/washington.jpg">
```

Comment: Wow. The Fiddle URL isn't even a link! Please post your code, here, not in an external location that may not be permanent.

Comment: Why do you have two #sis elements?

Comment: The example has a ton of 'cannot read property' errors. Maybe look into those.

Comment: Okay, that was a mistake my mine behalf.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/IyamSIM/L6umLkt8/

Comment: Have you even attempted to debug all the errors listed?

Comment: I will try to fix the errors now

Answer (score 0):

You could let CSS3 do the job for you.
Also why don't you create a random function generator? That's what you need after all, the one below will generate a number given a min and max value range.

```js
var EL_countdown = document.getElementById('countdown'),
  ELs_card = document.getElementsByClassName('card'),
  sec = 10;

// random generator
function rnd(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}


function countdown() {
  sec--;
  EL_countdown.innerHTML = !sec ? "End" : sec;
  if (!sec) return flyTime();
  else setTimeout(countdown, 100);
}

// Assign a random transition-timing and translate(x, y) position
function flyTime() {

  // assign CSS3 transition and transform to every card
  for (var i = 0; i < ELs_card.length; i++) {
    ELs_card[i].style.transition = rnd(1, 6) + "s";
    ELs_card[i].style.transform = "translate(" + rnd(20, 250) + "px, " + rnd(30, 120) + "px)";
  }
}

countdown();
```

```html
<div id="countdown">-</div>

<img class="card" src="//placehold.it/50x50/0bf">
<img class="card" src="//placehold.it/50x50/f0b">
<img class="card" src="//placehold.it/50x50/fb0">
```